# Qt Swipe Gesture not working

Tags: c++, qt, swipe, gestures

I am trying to enable a swipe gesture in my widget, but unfortunately it is not working.
I followed the documentations and examples that are provided by Qt.

Here is a part of my code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    grabGesture(Qt::SwipeGesture);
}

bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *event){
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Gesture)
        return gestureEvent(static_cast<QGestureEvent*>(event));
    return QWidget::event(event);
}

bool MainWindow::gestureEvent(QGestureEvent *event){
    if (QGesture *swipe = event->gesture(Qt::SwipeGesture))
        swipeTriggered(static_cast<QSwipeGesture *>(swipe));
    return true;
}

void MainWindow::swipeTriggered(QSwipeGesture *gesture){
    if (gesture->state() == Qt::GestureFinished){
        if (gesture->verticalDirection() == QSwipeGesture::Up)
            goButtomLabel();
        if (gesture->verticalDirection() == QSwipeGesture::Down)
            goUpperLabel();
        update();
    }
}

void MainWindow::goButtomLabel(){
    // does something here
}

void MainWindow::goUpperLabel(){
   // does something here
}
```

Is there anything wrong? Did I forget something?

I am new to Qt and also a beginner with C++, so I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you so much!

Comment: On which platform are you working?

Comment: I work with Qt4 on Linux/Ubuntu and I am using a multi-touch display.